# How to swap two words that are connected via hyphen using sed

Tags: unix, sed

I need to swap two words that are connected with a hyphen, e.g., `super-fast` -> `fast-super`, using extended regular expressions.

I have already searched through the internet and the solution I came up with:

```
sed -r "s/^\(.*\) \(.-\) \(.*\)/\3 \2 \1/" inputfile
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `sed "s/^\(.*\)-\(.*\)$/\2-\1/" inputfile`? `sed "s/\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\)-\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\)/\2-\1/" inputfile`?

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure you'll have exactly one `-`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)-(.*)/\2-\1/' <<< 'super-fast'
fast-super
```

If you have more than one hyphen, this will swap the parts before and after the *last* one:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)-(.*)/\2-\1/' <<< 'one-two-three'
three-one-two
```

If you want to swap around the *first* one:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^-]*)-(.*)/\2-\1/' <<< 'one-two-three'
two-three-one
```

This uses `[^-]*` in the first capture group: zero or more of "not a hyphen".

Notice that if you use `-r` (or the equivalent `-E`) for extended regular expressions in sed, capture groups must *not* be escaped.